# Is there a method to convert a Butterworth response into Chebyshev and Bessel responses?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, active-filter, theory

I wonder if once there is a completed/aproximated a design model of any of the responses mentionated, it can be operated mathematically (or there is a method/recipe) to generate the other responses?

As I understand the only way is to make the aproximations for all of the responses, say, make 3 designs for the same circuit

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can slide a Chebychev variable ripple to zero and get a Butterworth, Falstad's Analog Filter will also show the poles moving with all these variations incl. Bessel

Comment: The transfer function: $$H(s)=\dfrac{1}{s^2+as+1}$$ is a lowpass whose response can be varied to match anything from Gaussian to Chebsyshev (including Bessel, transitional, Butterworth, Legendre, ultraspherical, Papoulis, Halpern, Pascal, whatever else I don't remember, and then some), as long as it's an all-pole filter.